# Scraping only jpg's from list of URLs with wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to scrape only the .jpg's from a list of urls using wget.

I have tried `wget -r -A.jpg http://url.com/page1` but it downloads the entire site.

I also saw this example for scraping a list of urls `wget -i download-file-list.txt` so I tried this `wget -i -A.jpg download-file-list.txt` but it is only downloading the html not the jpg image.

Is there a way to give it an HTML page and have it only download a certain type of image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget -r` is recursive, so it's going to check the entire site. Set `-l` to limit the depth of the recursion.

As for the rest - you need to change `-A.jpg` to `-A "jpg"` in order to use the accept flag. The arguments for it are a comma separated list, so if you wanted to include jpg and png extensions, then change `"jpg"` to `"jpg,png"`.

Comment: You can also set the `-np` flag to not ascend into the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks @Xarus! It worked but also downloaded all the related folders and directories on the page. Is there a way to only download the jpg if I dont know the direct url to it? Also, lets say there is 2 jpg's that have different html id's can I select only jpg's that have a certain class or ID? Thanks again!

Comment: If you add the `-nd` flag, it will not grab directories - as for specific class/IDs, I think this is a little outside the scope of wget :(